# Capturing latency data with Core Audio

Tags: audio, core-audio, latency

I wrote this code to create an audio file sine.aif using Audio ToolBox framework.

I'm interested in capturing the data latency of this file without running it my phone, just running it on the command line and capturing the time. Is this possible? I do not have much knowledge with Core Audio.

Here is the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

#define SAMPLE_RATE 44100                   
#define DURATION 5.0                        
#define FILENAME_FORMAT @"%0.3f-sine.aif"  

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage:CAToneFileGenerator 261.526\n");
        return -1;
    }

    double hz = atof(argv[1]); 
    assert (hz > 0);
    NSLog (@"generating %f hz tone", hz);

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:FILENAME_FORMAT, hz]; 

    NSString *filePath = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager]currentDirectoryPath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    //Prepare the format
    AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd;   
    memset(&asbd, 0, sizeof(asbd));     
    asbd.mSampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE;     

    asbd.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    asbd.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsBigEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    asbd.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    asbd.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    asbd.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    asbd.mBytesPerFrame = 2;
    asbd.mBytesPerPacket = 2;

    //Set up the file
    AudioFileID audioFile;
    OSStatus audioErr = noErr;
    audioErr = AudioFileCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, kAudioFileAIFFType, &asbd, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &audioFile); 
    assert(audioErr == noErr);

    //Start writing samples
    long maxSampleCount = SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION; 
    //NSLog (@"maxSampleCount %long", maxSampleCount);
    long sampleCount = 0;
    UInt32 bytesToWrite = 2;
    double wavelengthInSamples = SAMPLE_RATE / hz; 
    NSLog (@"wavelengthInSamples %f", wavelengthInSamples);

    while (sampleCount < maxSampleCount) {
        for (int i=0; i < wavelengthInSamples; i++) {
            // sine wave
            SInt16 sample = CFSwapInt16HostToBig ((SInt16)SHRT_MAX * sin(2 * M_PI * (i / wavelengthInSamples)));
            audioErr = AudioFileWriteBytes(audioFile, false, sampleCount*2, &bytesToWrite, &sample);
            assert(audioErr == noErr);
            sampleCount++;
        }
    }
    audioErr = AudioFileClose(audioFile); 
    assert(audioErr == noErr);
    NSLog (@"wrote %d samples", sampleCount);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by data latency?

Comment: Capture the number in milliseconds between a moment that I pressed 'play' and the moment that the sound is executed in sound system of my notebook.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without actually running it on the hardware.

Comment: That was I thinking... :(